# Deriving the PDF of $\chi_k^2$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{k}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $X_i\sim N(0,1)$, then, the random variable $\sum_{i=1}^kX_i^2\sim\chi_k^2$. It is easy to show that the PDF of $\chi_1^2$ is
\begin{equation}
f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x}{2})x^{-\frac{1}{2}}1_{[0,\infty)}\text{. }
\end{equation}
It is known that if $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous and independent with PDF's $f$ and $g$ respectively, then $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous with PDF $h(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)g(y)dy$, furthermore, if $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are absolutely continuous and independent, then $\sum_{i=1}^kY_i$ is absolutely continuous with PDF
\begin{equation}
h(x_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cdots\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(x_1-\sum_{i=2}^kx_i)\prod_{i=2}^{k}f_i(x_i)dx_2\cdots dx_k\text{, }
\end{equation}
where $f_i$ is the PDF of $Y_i$. Applying this to $Y_i:=X_i^2$ and simplifying we have that
\begin{equation}
h(x_1)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^k\exp\left(-\frac{x_1}{2}\right)
\int_{0}^\infty\cdots\prod_{i=3}^kx_i^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{x_1-\sum_{i=3}^kx_i}((x_1-\sum_{i=3}^kx_i)-x_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_2\cdots dx_k\text{, }\end{equation}
performing the innermost integral we have that it equals $\pi$, so
\begin{equation}
h(x_1)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^k\exp\left(-\frac{x_1}{2}\right)\pi\int_{0}^\infty\cdots\prod_{i=4}^kx_i^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^\infty x_3^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_3\cdots dx_k\text{, }
\end{equation}
but now, the innermost integral diverges, so, obviously, something is wrong over here. Could you help me to spot the mistake?

### Edit

**The main question is already solved (thanks!)**, now, just for fun, if we define $a_i=x_1-\sum_{j=i}^kx_j$, then, it is clear that $a_i=a_{i+1}-x_{i+1}$, so the problem now is to compute
\begin{equation}
h(x_1)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^k\exp\left(-\frac{x_1}{2}\right)\pi\int_{0}^{a_k}x_k^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdots\int_{0}^{a_4}x_4^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{a_3} x_3^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_3dx_4\cdots dx_k\text{, }
\end{equation}
computing the first innermost integrals trying to find a pattern shows us the following:
\begin{gather}
\int_{0}^{a_2}(a_2-x_2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_2=\pi a_2^0\\
\int_{0}^{a_3}(a_3-x_3)^{0}x_3^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_2=2a_3^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\int_{0}^{a_4}(a_4-x_4)^{\frac{1}{2}}x_4^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx_2=\frac{\pi}{2}a_4^1\text{, }\\
\end{gather}
the pattern seems clear for the $a$'s, but not so much for the $\pi$'s and the non-$\pi$ coefficients. It follows like this $\frac{4}{3}$, $\frac{3\pi}{8}$, $\frac{16}{15}$, $\frac{5\pi}{16}$, $\frac{32}{35}$, $\frac{35\pi}{128}$, $\frac{256}{315}$, $\frac{63\pi}{256}$,... and **it's kind of weird!!** Seems really difficult to find a pattern here with the goal of finally deriving by induction the PDF of $\chi_k^2$ (I know characteristic functions are the way to go but still want to have some fun!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost integral should have upper limit $x$, not $\infty$. For example, the $\chi_2^2$ case reduces to$$\int_0^x\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{y(x-y)}}\exp\frac{-x}{2}dy\stackrel{y=x\sin^2t}{=}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\pi}\exp\frac{-x}{2}dt=\frac12\exp\frac{-x}{2}.$$

Here's an alternative approach: since the $\chi_1^2$ distribution has characteristic function $(1-2it)^{-1/2}$, the $\chi_k^2$ case has cf $(1-2it)^{-k/2}$. Only one PDF can have this cf; by inspection, it's $\frac{2^{-k/2}}{\Gamma(k/2)}x^{k/2-1}\exp\frac{-x}{2}$ on $[0,\,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

After proving that any $X_i^2\sim \chi_{(1)}^2$ as per the fact that $X_i$ independent from $X_j$ implies also $X_i^2$ is independent from $X_j^2$ your pdf can be immediately derivated using MGF and its properties